# Multiple object of shared preference deletes data

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using shared preferences throughout my application. I'm having a problem though. I think my data is being lost on background.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(pref_data, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("isDriverLogin", "True");
editor.putString("driverPassword", driverPassword);
editor.putString("carrierId", carrierId);
editor.putString("CCTID", cctid);
editor.putString("shipment", entityShipment);
editor.putString("isAccepted", "");
editor.commit();
```

And somewhere in the app I create another object and edit just one portion of the data

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(pref_data, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("isDriverLogin", "True");
editor.commit();
```

I'm doing this throughout my application. Editing just one or two data. But at some point my app crashes or the expected behavior is not happening. This behaviors are dependent on my preference data.

I tried fixing it by just creating one object of share preferences and always edit them with all the data. For example I have 5 data on shared preferences. If I just need to edit one, I will still put some data on the other 4 just to make sure nothing is being overwritten.

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: make sure are you calling `editor.commit();` or `editor.apply();` after editing preference data

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include that one on my post.

Comment: getSharedPreference modes should be     MODE_PRIVATE or
    MODE_WORLD_READABLE (deprecated) or
    MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE (deprecated) or
    MODE_MULTI_PROCESS. Havent seen one with CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY or it has been documented.